# Conditional Expectation and where a RandomVariable is Infinite

Tags: probability-theory

My question here is:

If $Y$ is positive on $\{\Omega, A, P\}$ and $G$ is a $\sigma$ subfield of $A$
show that $\{Y=+\infty\} \subset \{E[Y|G]=+\infty\}$ a.s.

I'm not even sure how to begin solving this problem. I've tried thinking about a particular $\omega$ where $Y(\omega) = \infty$, but I don't know how to use to say anything about $E[Y|G]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix some finite positive integer $n$ and consider the events $A_n=[E(Y\mid G)\leqslant n]$ and $B_n=A_n\cap[Y=+\infty]$, then $E(E(Y\mid G);A_n)\leqslant nP(A_n)$ and $E(Y;A_n)\geqslant E(Y;B_n)\geqslant+\infty P(B_n)$ hence $+\infty P(B_n)\leqslant nP(A_n)\leqslant n$. In particular, $+\infty P(B_n)$ is finite hence $P(B_n)=0$.

This holds for every $n$ hence $N=\bigcup\limits_nB_n=[E(Y\mid G)\lt+\infty,Y=+\infty]$ has probability zero, thus $[Y=+\infty]\subseteq[E(Y\mid G)=+\infty]\cup N$ where $P(N)=0$. This is the strongest conclusion one can reach since $E(Y\mid G)$ is only defined up to negligible events.

Note that the statement "$A\subset B$ almost surely", for some non-random vents $A$ and $B$, is misleading.

Comment: Could you explain the end of your second line?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: I don't understand where the left or right parts of the inequality come from.

Comment: Please be **much** more specific. Which inequality? What **exactly** are you failing to get in it? Certainly not both sides of an inequality at the same time...

Comment: At the end of your second line, you have an inequality.  I don't know where the left or right parts come from, or what the left side means.  If I knew that, I might be able to see why it's true...but I don't see that yet either.

Comment: Since you **still** did not say which part it was, I assume this is $E(Y;A_n)\geqslant E(Y;B_n)\geqslant+\infty P(B_n)$ you are asking about (this is the end of the second line on my screen, but the notion is highly device-dependent, which is why I fail to understand why you use it...). Then $Y\geqslant0$ and $B_n\subseteq A_n$ account for the first inequality and $Y=+\infty$ on $B_n$ accounts for the second one.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even think about it being displayed differently.  I'm referring to $E(E(Y|G);A_n) \leq nP(A_n)$.  I'm always hesitant to put latex in comments because I can't see if it's displaying correctly.

Comment: It is displaying correctly. This inequality is a direct consequence of the fact that $E(Y\mid G)\leqslant n$ on $A_n$. Quite generally, if $Z\leqslant z$ on $C$ then $E(Z;C)\leqslant zP(C)$.

Comment: Does $E(Z;C)$ mean something different than $E(Z|C)$? Because if $P(C)=.5$ and $Z:=1$ everywhere, then it is not true that $E(Z;C) \leq 5 \cdot P(C)$.

Comment: ?? Yes it does.

Comment: What does it mean then? Because I checked somewhereelse when I saw your notation, and they said it means the same thing for conditional probability:                     http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10234/meaning-of-probability-notations-pzd-w-and-pzd-w

Comment: Sorry but where do you see *expectations* in this link? Anyway, $E(Z;C)=E(Z\mathbf 1_C)$ and $E(Z\mid C)=E(Z;C)/P(C)$. Thus, if $P(C)=0.5$ and $Z=1$ everywhere (your example) then $E(Z;C)=0.5=P(C)$ and $E(Z\mid C)=1$.

Comment: Thanks, I worked all the way through the proof and understand it.  Regarding $A \subset B$ a.s being misleading -- to keep the "a.s.", should you reword it to say that for any $\omega$, if $Y(\omega) = +\infty$ then $E[Y|G(\omega)]=+\infty$ a.s.?

Comment: I would not reword it like that since E[Y|G(ω)] does not exist and since the "a.s." at the end of your comment is quite mysterious. The statement $[ω\mid Y(ω)=+∞]\subseteq[ω\mid E[Y|G](ω)=+∞]$ is correct, up to a negligible set.

Comment: As I'm looking at it again, there is something I don't see.  Why is $\infty P(B_n) \leq nP(A_n)$? I'm guessing it's because $E[Y;B_n] \leq E[Y;A_n] \leq E[E[Y|G];A_n]$ but I can't see why $E[Y;A_n] \leq E[E[Y|G];A_n]$.

Comment: The event $A_n$ is in $G$ since $A_n$ depends only on $E(Y\mid G)$ which is $G$-measurable, hence $E(Y;A_n)=E(E(Y\mid G);A_n)$.